# Drop an index in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.1, concurrency

I had created an index wrongly and now I am trying to drop that index. Since the table is large, dropping the index is taking lot of time. Is there any other way to drop the index quickly?

Comment: If it's taking that long, it's probably being locked by some other transaction. Check `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: See also: postgresql - Why does dropping an index take longer than creating it? -
https://stackoverflow.com/q/26346147/

Answer (score 12):

You could try `DROP INDEX [ CONCURRENTLY ] name`

- CONCURRENTLY

  Drop the index without locking out concurrent selects, inserts,
  updates, and deletes on the index's table. A normal DROP INDEX
  acquires exclusive lock on the table, blocking other accesses until
  the index drop can be completed. With this option, the command
  instead waits until conflicting transactions have completed.
- Here's the documentation for postgres 9.2:
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-dropindex.html

**Note: This feature is not available before postgres 9.2.**

- Here's the documentation for postgres 9.1:
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-dropindex.html
- This is similar to `ONLINE = ON` option in SQL Server:
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176118.aspx

Comment: DROP  INDEX  CONCURRENTLY  idx_treenodes_mid_nid ; shows me syntax error

Comment: What is the syntax error? Which version of postgres are you using?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONCURRENTLY"
LINE 1: DROP  INDEX  CONCURRENTLY  idx_treenodes_mid_nid ..... Im using 9.1 version

Answer (score 0):

Somehow maintainance_work_mem is not considered as maintenance operations and it does not have any implication to speed up the drop index process.

Dropping the index concurrently seems to be the only option but I won't suggest to directly run it from Pgadmin or Psql terminal. 
Because if the session gets terminated or due to timeout, it may leave index inconsistent.

Hope this helps.
Aj

http://www.postgresql-blog.com/